# Multiple branches in the same commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I have a commit which contains multiple (unwanted)branches, by
git log --graph i got this:

```
commit 417bb7dfd7d7230fd1c859414d2aa231e72e24e6 (HEAD -> Feature1, master, Feature2)
```

How can i move Feature1,Feature2 branches from commit 417bb7dfd7d7230fd1c859414d2aa231e72e24e6 to different commits?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be predicated on a misunderstanding.

These branches are not *in the commit*.

In git, branches are labels pointing to commits. A commit can have any number (zero, four, a thousand, whatever) of branches pointing at it.

```
A---B---C---D
     \   \   \
      \   \   master
       \   \
        \   branch-abc
         \
          branch-xyz
```

Here above, `master`, `branch-abc` and `branch-xyz` happen to point at different commits, but if you did

```
git checkout branch-abc
git merge master
```

You would then get

```
A---B---C---D
     \       \
      \       master, branch-abc
       \    
        branch-xyz
```

...where, yes, `master` and `branch-abc` *do* point to the same commit.

---

If, for any reason, you **do** need to move or delete a branch, this is easy (but then again, I have to stress the important part, being to understand what branches are for)

```
# move a branch to commit abc123 (when the branch is NOT checked out)
git branch -f my_branch abc123

# or if the branch IS checked out
git reset --hard abc123

# delete a branch
git branch -d my_branch

# ...which will complain in case the branch isn't fully merged yet
# in which case you can then force it
git branch -D my_branch
```

Comment: thank you for your help,time and effort. After a bit practise it showed me that there were not in the same commit,its just shows because those were empty branches

Comment: @Andrewboy Yes, that's a common situation. No big worries :-)

Comment: @Andrewboy: there is no such thing as an "empty branch". If two branch names point to the same commit `a123456`, *all* commits from `a123456` on backwards are in *both* branches.